# Issue with Flexbox Height Growth

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The issue I am having is with my Flexbox growing in height when I enter content inside of it. I am not 100% sure why this is happening, but I believe it has something to do with it not being in an absolute position and thus keeping its height property.

Included is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/mdiggss/pen/vxZYej) where I have the HTML and CSS setup for the Flexbox style site that I am making (Also included the Snippet below) Here is so info about it

```css
body p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px !important; }

.home-wrap {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background 1.5s ease-in-out; }

.home-sections {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 775px;
  max-width: 775px; }
  .home-sections section {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    overflow: hidden; }
  .home-sections .flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; }
  .home-sections .flex--center {
    justify-content: center; }

.col-1 {
  text-align: center; }

.alignTop {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 100%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out; }

.alignCenter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%; }

.alignBottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 100%;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out; }

section.about {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220%;
  left: 100%;
  box-shadow: -6px 6px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
  animation: enticing-grow 2s 2;
  background-color: #CB7E15; }
  section.about .displayB {
    display: block;
    text-align: center; }
    section.about .displayB h1 {
      margin-top: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
      text-shadow: 5px 5px 8px white; }
    section.about .displayB p {
      font-size: 16px; }
  section.about .mike-faq {
    display: flex;
    opacity: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out; }

section.setup {
  width: calc(55% - 6px);
  height: 80%;
  box-shadow: -8px 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  background-color: #004EFF; }

section.social {
  width: calc(45% - 6px);
  height: 55%;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #585656; }
  section.social:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.5);
    z-index: 2; }
  section.social .displayB {
    display: block; }
    section.social .displayB p {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 10px; }
  section.social .social-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around; }
    section.social .social-wrap .twitter-logo {
      background-image: url(/assets/img/twitter-logo.gif);
      background-size: contain;
      width: 55px;
      height: 55px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 #1DA1F2; }
    section.social .social-wrap .email-logo {
      background-image: url(/assets/img/gmail-logo.png);
      background-size: contain;
      width: 55px;
      height: 55px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 #E70F10; }
    section.social .social-wrap .facebook-logo {
      background-image: url(/assets/img/facebook-logo.png);
      background-size: contain;
      width: 55px;
      height: 55px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px #3C5A98; }
    section.social .social-wrap .github-logo {
      background-image: url(/assets/img/github-logo.png);
      background-size: contain;
      width: 55px;
      height: 55px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 #E04006; }

section.twitch {
  width: calc(55% - 6px);
  height: 80%;
  box-shadow: -8px -8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  background-color: #5A3E85; }
  section.twitch h1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center; }
  section.twitch p {
    font-size: 16px; }
  section.twitch .displayB {
    display: block;
    text-align: center; }

.button {
  color: #5A3E85; }

section.webdesign {
  width: calc(45% - 6px);
  height: 53%;
  box-shadow: 8px -8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  background-color: #1F843A; }

section.youtube {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 140%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  box-shadow: -8px 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #CC181E; }
```

```html
<div class="home-wrap">
  <div class="home-sections">
    <div class="alignTop">
      <section class="twitch">
        <div class="flex flex--center displayB">
          <h1>Twitch</h1>
          <!--           <p>I've been livestreaming on Twitch since it's days as Justin.tv - I plan to pick it back up again once I can figure out a schedule</p> -->
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="webdesign">
        <div class="flex flex--center">
          <p>Web Design</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="alignCenter">
      <section class="youtube">
        <div class="flex flex--center">
          <P>YouTube</P>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="about grown">
        <div class="flex flex--center displayB">
          <h1>What's Going on, Mike here, and Welcome to my Site!</h1>
          <p>I'm your typical 26 year old nerd, who loves computers, video games, pretty much anything tech. Along with that, I have a ton of hobbies that range from playing music to stock investments. </p>
          <p>I've always been interested in, and worked on my web design skills, but it wasn't until the past few months where I decided this is what I am passionate about.</p>
          <p>With that said, click around the site to learn more about me. All panels are expandable clickable which will allow you to learn more about "Mike" and who I am!</p>
          <div class="mike-faq">
            <p>FAQ 1</p>
            <p>FAQ 2 </p>
            <p>FAQ 3</p>
            <p>FAQ 4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="alignBottom">
      <section class="setup">
        <div class="flex flex--center">
          <p>Setup</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="social">
        <div class="flex flex--center displayB">
          <p>Social</p>
          <div class="social-wrap">
            <div class="twitter-logo"></div>
            <div class="email-logo"></div>
            <div class="facebook-logo"></div>
            <div class="github-logo"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
```

1 - I have a wrapping div around the site content so I can control the flow and background of the back

2 - I have another wrapping div for each "Row" of Flexbox so I can have them align in different areas (Top is aligned Flex-Start, Center is aligned Flex-Center and Bottom is aligned Flex-Bottom)

3 - The 2 Center Flexboxes (YouTube and About) are set with Absolute position so I am able to have the "About" section grow out and overlap the top and bottom sections.

4 - I have all the fleboxes set with % height and width so they will scale with the window value.

5 - Inside of each FlexBox section, I have a container so that I can manipulate the content and move it around so it fits within their parent flexbox.

Now, I am not 100% sure if all the nesting and parent/child elements is the best way to handle what I am trying to do, but I haven't been able to visualize it any other way and get it work (outside of the way I am doing it).

So - to go over it again, inside of the "Twitch: panel I have a `<p>` section that when I uncomment, the flexbox will grow in height, rather than remain the same. However, in the "About" section, this doesn't happen. The only difference I am able to see is that the "About" section is `position: absolute`.

Comment: You have a lot going on in your layout. Consider removing all unnecessary code and reproducing the problem in a simpler example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play around by giving `alignTop, alignCenter and alignBottom` heights.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWEgMK : try commenting in and out what you said then find the adequates values for heights you are happy with.

```
.alignTop {
  height:33%;}

.alignCenter {
  height:25%;}

.alignBottom {
  height:20%;}
```

Not sure that's exactly what you want but to be honnest there is way too much clutter in your codepen for us to really want to try :) Are the animations even relevant ?

Comment: much appreciated with the advice as I do realize I posted a lot of un-needed code. I went through and edited the codepen previously but for some reason the pen didn't update (i must not have been logged in)


Anyway, setting the heights on the ".align" elements works perfectly and allowed me to add content to the child containers without adjusting the height. I'm guessing the top flex level will always grow unless it has a specified height?

Comment: @MikeDiglio You could play around with flex grow as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow

Comment: I was looking into Flex-Grow, but I don't think I was grasping concept properly. Your answer actually helps me visualize and test this. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

rather than % heights you may want to let flexbox handle the heights for you, as in grow to the viewport as it is designed to do but then use a max-height with a vh unit rather than a % value (like max-height: 75vh instead of max-height:75%). vh uses the viewport to scale not the parent div.